# 400 Bad request for Token Obtain Pair, Django REST simpleJWT and Vue 3 composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, django-rest-framework

Having a problem getting the refresh and access tokens, when sending the form from my vue app to the django rest api. CORS are enabled. Signing up through the rest api page and using postman doesn't cause any issues. When i send a post request with Vue, `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/ 400 (Bad Request)` pops up in the console. + how can i store/ display the returned refresh and access tokens? Any recommendations?

```
<template>
  <div>
    auth 1
    <div id="authenticationDiv">
      <form action="" v-on:submit.prevent="loginUser">
        <input type="text" v-model="username" />
        <input type="text" v-model="password" />
        <button @click="loginUser(username, password)">
          login
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>acess: {{ accessToken }}</div>
      <div>refresh: {{ refreshToken }}</div>
      <button @click="DisplayText(username, password)">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    const username = ref("aleksisDjango");
    const password = ref("zimbabwe123");

    const accessToken = ref("");
    const refreshToken = ref("");

    const TOKEN_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/";

    // function getCookie(name) {
    //   let cookieValue = null;
    //   if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
    //     const cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    //     for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    //       const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
    //       // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
    //       if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === name + "=") {
    //         cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
    //         break;
    //       }
    //     }
    //   }
    //   return cookieValue;
    // }
    // const csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");

    async function loginUser(username, password) {
    // var csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
      fetch(TOKEN_URL, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
            // "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: username,
          password: password,
        }),
      }).then((response) => {

        username = "";
        password = "";

        return response;
      });
    }

    function DisplayText(username, password) {
      console.log(`username:${username}, password:${password}`);
    }

    return {
      username,
      password,
        // csrftoken,
      loginUser,
      accessToken,
      refreshToken,
      DisplayText,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check `ALLOWED_HOSTS`:

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

or to match any:

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

2. Set headers and catch for error, maybe there will be more information?

```js
fetch(TOKEN_URL, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: username,
    password: password
  })
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("ERROR", error);
  });
```

3. Check a web developer console? How does your request look like? Do you send proper data in the request?
4. If you are using DRF with JWT, the CSRF token is not required by default.
5. I store token in localStorage. You can check details in my [tutorial on React Token-Based Authentication to Django REST API Backend](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/react-token-based-authentication-django/). It is for React, but for Vue will be very similar. At the end of the tutorial, there is also discussion about storing token in localStorage vs cookies httpOnly (worth reading).

Comment: added the `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`, copied the code from the second point. Still get an error. Changed the `console.log(response)` to `console.log(response.json());` When i submit the username and password, i get 2 pending promises. The first promise holds the object for the submitted info and the second holds `[[PromiseState]]: 'fulfliled', [[PromiseResult]]: Object`, which has the access and refresh tokens. Maybe have an idea what i'm doing wrong? :D